# Can we use both Direct Query and import option in a single Power BI Report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm Trying to create a Power BI Report where I have Two data Sources. One is a SQL Server Database and the other is an excel file. I was wondering If I could import the Excel File and get the data from the SQL server database using a Direct query.
Is that possible?

Comment: As of July 2018 release, using import AND direct query (known as "composite models") is supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-composite-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI currently doesn't support mixing `DirectQuery` and `Import` data sources in the same report. You have to choose one or the other for the entire report.

In your case, you could import the data from the Excel file and also get the data from the SQL Server, using the `Import mode` for both (and have a copy of the data embedded in your report file).

If you import the SQL data using `DirectQuery`, then you won't be able to import the Excel file.

[There's a feature request to allow mixing `DirectQuery` and `Import` which you can vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10321215-allow-mixing-direct-query-and-imported-tables-in-a).

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?  I would like to publish my desktop dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Since 2021-01-19 Power BI supports composite models.

[composite models in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models)